# Can I modify a selector used as param of insertAfter via other jQuery methods?

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I'd like to move the second tr parent of a selected element, to go after the second tr parent of another selected element. I can do this a number of ways in 2 lines but can I do it in one?

Due to a terrible CMS that nests a bunch of elements and gives ID attributes for only a few, here's my starting HTML structure:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="element1">
                            [...]
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="element2">
                            [...]
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="element3">
                            [...]
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a much larger number than three of this repeating pattern, of course, but that's the structure. I need to rearrange these outer tr elements. I have tried this:

```
jQuery("div#element3").parents("tr").eq(1).detach().insertAfter("div#element1").parents("tr").eq(1);
```

but when that runs, it behaves as if I've typed:

```
jQuery("div#element3").parents("tr").eq(1).detach().insertAfter("div#element1");
```

Is there not a way, in one line, to do an insertAfter on not the element selected by its selector parameter, but rather on an element selected by applying additional methods to the result of that selector? Doubling up the parens around the selector plus the following methods to try to group them as the target of the operation does not work.

Obviously I can solve the problem by declaring a var to hold ("div#element1").parents("tr").eq(1), and pass that as the argument to insertAfter--but I can't believe I can't do this in one line of code, and since I have to do a ton of these manipulations, in an arbitrary, non-loopable way, I'd for sure prefer one line.

Thanks!

Comment: So you don't have control over the source html if I'm reading this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the parents traverse of the second div inside the `insertAfter()` and make it a new jQuery object

Can also remove the `detach()`. That will be done automatically since an element can't exist in 2 places without being cloned.

```
jQuery("div#element3").parents("tr").eq(1).detach()
     .insertAfter(jQuery("div#element1").parents("tr").eq(1));
```

Personally I would break this up. Getting it all on one long line vs making it readable is worth extra lines

Something like:

```
var $toMove = jQuery("div#element3").parents("tr").eq(1);
var $target = jQuery("div#element1").parents("tr").eq(1);
$target.after($toMove)
```

---

One final suggestion would be that if you have multiple traverses like this to do would be try to add some classes on page load to make traversals simpler later on

Then you can do something like:

```
var $toMove = jQuery("div#element3").closest("tr.main-rows");
var $target = jQuery("div#element1").closest("tr.main-rows");
$target.after($toMove)
```

Comment: Oh duh: when I first read your answer I thought "but I DID move it inside the insertAfter() and I got errors!!!1"

Turns out I also needed to actually type "jQuery" in front of the selector. That's all I was doing wrong. Headdesk, and thanks. Your code is missing a close paren right after "div#element1" but otherwise that did the trick.

Good tip on removing detach(), though, and you're right on adding classes--it was how I was getting around my "bug" actually, rather than declaring vars, but this is one big annoying one-time thing so I'm gonna let it, and readability, ride. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I've worked on old legacy pages like that before trying to modernize features for people that wouldn't listen to idea of rebuilding whole page

Comment: That missing jQuery bug was partly from trying to get it all into one expression.

Comment: legacy systems: job security at the low low price of your entire sanity. thanks for fixing the missing paren in your answer to help people as blind as I am in the future!

Comment: Irony is that rebuilding whole page takes less time when considering both ends and makes it easier to be responsive